# OpenProcess() returns 0, if not started from VS

Tags: c++

I made a simple injector and a dll with an OpenProcess function inside. Starting from Visual Studio 2012 works and OpenProcess() returns the right handle but when I inject the dll with the exe OpenProcess() does not find the right handle. Can you tell me why?
EDIT:

```
  DWORD WINAPI Function( LPVOID lpParam  )
   {
        pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
        HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

        if (Process32First(snapshot, &pe32) == TRUE)
        {
            if (Process32Next(snapshot, &pe32) == TRUE)
            {
                if (_stricmp(pe32.szExeFile, "my.exe") == 0)
                {  
                    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);
                    if(!hProcess)
                        {
                        MessageBox(NULL,"Error","",0);
                    }

                    else {
  for(;;)
    {
    ...
        }
}}}}}
```

When I inject the dll I get the messagebox. GetLastError returns "Access Denied".

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `dwDesiredAccess` parameter of [`OpenProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx).

Take a look at the following example:

[Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701.aspx)

If it doesn't work, post some code and try to run your process as admin.